# How to get range of selected dates using android Caldroid library?

Tags: android, caldroid

I have implemented android [Caldroid](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid) library to my project.

and already get selected dates

[image: I]

I tried

```
caldroidFragment.setSelectedDates(fromDate, toDate);
```

but, it does not let me get range of selected dates, and demo does not show how to get range

I also use, which is object but not a String,

```
caldroidFragment.getCaldroidData().get(caldroidFragment.SELECTED_DATES);
```

So, anyone have any idea, how to get selected dates ranges in number?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I got another way to get exactly days between `fromDate` and `toDate`,

The formula is

```
String getNoDays = String.format("%d", 
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(Math.abs(fromDate.getTime() - toDate.getTime())));
```

Hope it will be helpful to others as well.